# Modify Files using imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using imacros for sending emails to subscribers and I need to know how to modify a datasource file in order to prevent duplication. I am using JS script to call iim script where the iim is provided with a file that contains email addresses.

I should send 200 Emails per click. I need to make a loop for the emails to be added to the -send to section- but I recently discovered that I can't make a loop inside iim script so i figure out that the best way is to delete the read record and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your original file '**test_edit.txt**' be as follow:

```
"1
2
3
4
5"
```

Play the following macro:

```
SET file "test_edit.txt"
SET folder {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}
SET !DATASOURCE {{file}}
SET newCol EVAL("var newCol = '{{!COL1}}'.split(/\s+/); newCol.shift(); newCol;")
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{newCol}}'.replace(/,/g, '\\n');")
FILEDELETE NAME={{folder}}\{{file}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{folder}} FILE={{file}}
```

Then you've got a modified file that looks like this:

```
"2
3
4
5"
```

Comment: So i will add the input command after

Comment: {
SET file "test_edit.txt"
SET folder {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}
SET !DATASOURCE {{file}}
SET newCol EVAL("var newCol = '{{!COL1}}'.split(/\s+/); newCol.shift(); newCol;")
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#app>DIV>DIV>DIV>SPAN>DIV>SPAN>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>INPUT" CHARS="{{!COL1}}"
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{newCol}}'.replace(/,/g, '\\n');")
FILEDELETE NAME={{folder}}\{{file}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{folder}} FILE={{file}}
}

Comment: The input is taking the hole file